# Getting all submissions for the past two months from a particular subreddit (using PRAW)?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I was trying to get all the /r/politics posts for the last two months with all the comments and the user details. How do I do this using PRAW?

Should I go through the posts in `get_hot()`? Any ideas on how to go about this? Are there any time-stamp methods that I can take advantage of?

Comment: Still looking for a way to get it done. I don't know what to use.

Comment: Are you using PRAW 3 or 4?

Comment: I have not ported to 4.0 but I am planning to. So 4.0 i guess.

Comment: But I can keep working with 3.6 as well so anything goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Cloudsearch syntax](https://www.reddit.com/wiki/search#wiki_cloudsearch_syntax) to search between 2 timestamps. The syntax is:

```
timestamp:START_UNIX_TIMESTAMP..END_UNIX_TIMESTAMP
```

If you are expecting less than 1000 entries to be returned, it should be relatively straightforward just to set up a search to do this. Search queries are limited to 1000 requests, though, so some special logic is required if more posts than this are expected.

To perform a search for any post in the last 2 months, try:

```
import time
current_timestamp = time.time()
# 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours * 60 days = 2 months
two_months_timestamp = current_timestamp - (60 * 60 * 24 * 60)
query = 'timestamp:{}..{}'.format(current_timestamp, two_months_timestamp)
results = reddit.subreddit('test').search(query, sort='new')
```

If you need to get more than 1000, I would suggest getting the timestamp of the last item in the search results, then storing the timestamp of that and searching for `timestamp:<current_timestamp>..<last_item_timestamp>` and repeat until there are no more results.

Comment: Just change the subreddit on the line `reddit.subreddit('test')` to whatever you like, and it should work equally well.

Comment: Great I will start working on this. I was wondering is there a way to get the top 1000 posts in the last month as we can using the UI?  In PRAW 3.6 we do something like this    `submissions = r.get_subreddit('politics').get_top(limit=1000)` .  Can we add some other parameters so as to specify the last month?

Comment: @meta yes, you can use `.get_top(time_filter='month')`. The options for `time_filter` are:  all, day, hour, month, week, year.

Comment: yes its working fine. Thanks!! For now I think I will do this itself instead of going through all the posts for the two months.

Comment: prawcore.exceptions.ServerError: received 503 HTTP response

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to share a complementary solution for anyone that uses PRAW 4+, using the [`Subreddit.submissions`](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html?highlight=search#praw.models.Subreddit.submissions) method that is perfect to search between timestamps. Using the same snipped code as the accepted answer:

```
import time
current_timestamp = time.time()
# 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours * 60 days = 2 months
two_months_timestamp = current_timestamp - (60 * 60 * 24 * 60)
results = reddit.subreddit('test').submissions(two_months_timestamp, current_timestamp)
```

Comment: This is several years old now but... This code no longer works as 'Subreddit' object has no attribute 'submissions'. Is there a new way of getting the submissions or comments in a subreddit between 2 timestampps?